# Visual Studio 2022 - Add HTML file and Add Javascript File options are not available

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have upgraded to VS 2022 recently. Now in the solution explorer, when I right-click a folder and want to add an HTML file or javascript file, the options are not available in the context menu. This was available in the earlier version.

Is there a way to get this option back?

Answer (score 1):

This option seems to show up for Web startup projects, but not for library projects.

As a workaround, I created [my own template](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kKfDltX8vi-gb-s90ATNobz8ERQoGbSL/view). You can place this file in "...\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Templates\ItemTemplates\JavaScript"

For those who want to make it from scratch, see [How to: Create item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-item-templates). I grabbed the icon from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/images-and-icons-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#examples-of-icons-with-language-modifiers).

Comment: I'm sure this will work but I shouldn't have to do this. If I take my project and open it via *.sln it doesn't give me web related items, CSS, HTML, JS etc. If I take the same project and say, File -> Open -> Folder it opens and I can add the aforementioned files. However, the open Folder method does not have any Team Explorer or Azure Dev Ops functionality. There has to be a better way

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem. The solution that work for me was to modify the visual studio installation, via the VS installer, and add the node.js development package[image] Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can add it from menu. Go to File **>** New **>** File **>** Choose Html/Js File. Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> => to create a new file.[image]

Comment: I do not see that option of HTML or Javascript file in the new file dialogue box.

Comment: Go-to File => New =>File => Html

Can you try Ctrl+N ?

Comment: I tried different options and it is not working. I am using VS 2022 Community